# Is there a way in Zapier to convert a python output to separate lines?

Tags: python, zapier

I have a Python output in a Zapier output that looks like this:

[image]

I want to be able to use this in the body of gmail as separate lines.  However, presently, it looks like this when I use that python output as the step.  The screenshot below is the email returned after I test.

[image]
Is there a filter or a pythonic way to do this within Zapier?

The output would ideally look like this:

```
https://hectv.sharefile.com/dxxxxxxxfcebd247d09
https://hectv.sharefile.com/dxxxxxxx729cd9494
https://hectv.sharefile.com/d-xxxxxx84622a
```

Thank you.

Comment: _I have a string in a Zapier output that looks like this:_ That looks like a Python list, can you confirm what the value actually is?

Answer (score 0):

William from Zapier answered this for me.

If we're generating a line item array with the code step and we need individual items, you'll want to add a Formatter - Utility - Line Item to Text action.

This action will go just after the Run Python step and should take the Sharefile Output as the input for the formatter. From there, the formatter can break the line item array down into individual text strings that you can assign in the zaps remaining steps. :)

For more information on Formatter check out our article here: https://zapier.com/help/create/format/get-started-with-formatter

For more info on Line Item to Text, check out this article: https://zapier.com/help/create/format/convert-line-items-into-text-strings

Using Line Item to Text, the zap won't care if there are 10 items or a single item, it should still return the same individual items. The main concern there is that the test that is done with Line Item to Text should be a test that include the MAX number of items. This way those items can be assigned in the following steps and used when they're present or ignored when they are not.